# Jquery Ajax error called

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Im calling my ajax on the following

```
function LoadAudit(value) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/GetAuditRecord/' + value,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#htmlResult").val(data.html);
        },
        error:function(data) {
            alert('error');
        },
    });
};
```

Which calls my controller

```
public JsonResult GetAuditRecord(string Id)
         {
              string html =_auditLogService.FindAllByAccount().Single(a => a.Id == Id).Comments ;
             return Json(new { html = result});
         }
```

Which works (data is looked up and ready  to pass back), but error is being fired in jquery, when success should be, what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `dataType` as `'JSON'` in ajax call as shown:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/Account/GetAuditRecord/' + value,
     dataType : 'JSON',
     success: function (data) {
         $("#htmlResult").val(data.html);
     },
     error:function(data) {
         alert('error');
     },
});
```

and change jsonresult in controller action as shown:

```
return Json(new { html = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the data type of the ajax call

```
dataType : 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Controller` return type:

```
return Json( new { html = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
```